# 2 conditional statements using &&

Tags: reactjs

I have an errors object for a login form which either has an error for the username, the password or both. I want to show all errors in one div.

I am using the inline logical && operator like below but not sure how to make it so it checks if there is an error with the password as well. So, I need this.state.errors.password in there too but not sure how.

```
    {this.state.errors.username && (
      <Alert variant="danger">{this.state.errors.username}</Alert>
    )}
```

I tried this but no error message shows up when I leave the password field empty when it should

```
        {this.state.errors.username && this.state.errors.password && (
          <Alert variant="danger">
            {this.state.errors.username} {this.state.errors.password}
          </Alert>
        )}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use or operator instead of and.

```
{(this.state.errors.username || this.state.errors.password) && (
    <Alert variant="danger">
       {this.state.errors.username} {this.state.errors.password}
    </Alert>
)}
```

this.state.errors.username && this.state.errors.password
if you use or operator it will render error both the fields have error

this.state.errors.username || this.state.errors.password
if you use or operator it will render error any of fields has an error.

Comment: Ah, okay. Didn't realise I could use the || operator in react ( I am a newb)

Comment: @user10980228 I'd be surprised if there is any language that supports && for and that doesn't also support || for or.

Comment: @phoog, true. But React is a real mind .... for me coming from php/mysql

Comment: @user10980228 fair enough.  It's easy to overlook even very obvious solutions when struggling with a new language.